# Converting websocket code from Python to Javascript

Tags: python, node.js, sockets, websocket

I have a problem implementing the client Python code to Javascript as the `open` listener seems never called

Python Code

```
HEADER_LENGTH = 10
IP = "SERVER_IP"
PORT = 8080

my_username = "user" # input("Username: ")
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((IP, PORT))
client_socket.setblocking(False)

username = my_username.encode("utf-8")
username_header = f"{len(username):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode('utf-8')
client_socket.send(username_header + username)
```

The server log will show

```
Waiting for next event
<socket.socket fd=3, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('SERVER_INTERNAL_IP', 8080)>
is notified_socket <socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('SERVER_INTERNAL_IP', 8080), raddr=('CLIENT_IP', 3237)> ('CLIENT_IP', 3237)
receive_message
Accepted new connection from CLIENT_IP:3237 username:user
 
Waiting for next event
<socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('SERVER_INTERNAL_IP', 8080), raddr=('CLIENT_IP', 3237)>
Closed connection from user
```

Javascript code

```
const HEADER_LENGTH = 10;

function addSpace(str, length) {
    var adding = length - str.length;
    var copy = str;
    if (adding > 0)
        for (var i = 0; i < adding; i++)
            copy += " ";
    return copy
}

(function(){
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + SERVER_IP + ":8080");
    ws.addEventListener('open', function(e){
        console.log('open', e);
        var username = encodeURI("user");
        var username_header = encodeURI(addSpace(username, HEADER_LENGTH));
        ws.send(username_header + username);
    });
    ws.addEventListener('message', function(e){console.log('msg', e)});

})();
```

The server log will show

```
Waiting for next event
<socket.socket fd=3, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('SERVER_INTERNAL_IP', 8080)>
is notified_socket <socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('SERVER_INTERNAL_IP', 8080), raddr=('CLIENT_IP', 3409)> ('CLIENT_IP', 3409)
 
Waiting for next event
```

Seems the open listener seems never called and console will return an error of `WebSocket connection to 'ws://SERVER_IP:8080/' failed`

Any suggestion to check out the difference between Python code and Javascript code

Answer (score 0):

I use gevent for async situations like these.  I love that it combines the normal html socket and upgrades if it sees a websocket attempt, makes the entire app very elegant and simple.

Below is an example of `bottle.py` and `gevent-websocket`:

```
import gevent
from gevent import monkey, signal, Timeout, sleep 
monkey.patch_all()
import signal
from gevent import signal_handler as sig
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler
from geventwebsocket import WebSocketError
import bottle
from bottle import get, post, template, request, response, route, abort


@get('/')
def _index():
    return template('index.html')

#websocket
@route('/ws/app')
def handle_websocket():
    ws = request.environ.get('wsgi.websocket')
    if not ws:
        abort(400, 'Expected WebSocket request.')
    ws.send('CONNECTED')
    while 1:
        message = None
        try:
            # The Timeout continues the polling after 2 seconds
            # as to not block on a recieve call. Allows for data update.  
            with Timeout(2, False) as timeout:
                message = ws.receive()
            if message:
                #do something with the message
                print(message)
        except WebSocketError:
            break
        except Exception as exc:
            sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    botapp = bottle.app()
    server = WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", 80), botapp, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    def shutdown():
        print('Shutting down ...')
        server.stop(timeout=60)
        exit(signal.SIGTERM)
    sig(signal.SIGTERM, shutdown)
    sig(signal.SIGINT, shutdown)  # CTRL C
    server.serve_forever()
```

Javascript would look a little like this:

```
var ws = new ReconnectingWebSocket('ws://localhost');
ws.reconnectInterval = 3000;
ws.maxReconnectAttempts = 100;

ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
    var wsmsg = JSON.parse(evt.data);
    // Do something with the wsmsg
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Could you explain how the python code ```connect``` is different with the Javascript ```new Websocket(...)```

Comment: javascript is how the web connects to the python server.  So you can use any websocket javascript library to connect and process (or send) a message to the websocket.

Comment: Would you mind to have a look on the code because I think it should be syntax issue? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  My code is correct.